# Japanese train etiquette: Is it acceptable to take a baby in the Shinkansen Green Car?

Tags: trains, japan, children, etiquette

The green carriage is of course first class. This would be our first preference with our 5 month old baby in lap, because of the presumably larger toilets for changing and whatnot.  However, our baby can cry a lot sometimes.

Speaking in terms of Japanese culture, should we avoid Green class tickets if we are taking aboard a potentially disruptive baby?

Comment: Just FYI, the difference in seating and facilities between Green and ordinary trains is quite minor.  As far as I can tell, their primary purpose is to allow JR to charge more money for reserved seats at busy times.

Comment: Just mentioning in case you were unaware of the proposed [Japanese culture](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59039/japanese-culture) site on Area51. :) Currently in commitment phase, so spread the word if you know anyone that might be interested.

Comment: @jpatokal, we're quite happy we chose the Green seat. In our train (Shinkansen Asama) the Green seat layout was 2x2 whereas the rest of the train was 3x3. We had zero risk of bothering an adjacent stranger and more room in the aisle to manouever a stroller. We chose the row closest to the baby changing room, which was actually 1x2.  Well worth the money.

Final note: our train had a changing room but no breastfeeding room.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it is acceptable. However, it is etiquette that if the baby does start to make noise that you take it to the "deck" area beyond the doors (where the bathrooms, telephone, vending machines, etc.) are.

This is the same protocol if you have to make or receive a telephone call, want to have a loud conversation with your seatmate, or do anything that might disturb other passengers.

I should note that this has nothing to do with the green car -- the main cars nominally operate under these protocols, it's just that the other passengers (and conductors) are less likely to enforce them.